# Restangular put() not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, restangular

I am using restangular with angular js. get() and post() are working good. But put is not working. Here is code -

```
$scope.submitFunction = function(isValid) {
                if (isValid) {
                    $scope.post = {};
                    $scope.post.id = $scope.form.id;
                    $scope.post.code = $scope.form.code;
                    $scope.post.description = $scope.form.description;
                    Restangular.one('manufacturing/process', $scope.processId). get(). then( function(response1) {

                        $scope.post.version = response1.data.version;
                        $scope.post.put().then(function(response) {
                            alert('updated');
                        }, function(response) {
                            alert('error);
                        });
                    }, function(response1) {
                            alert('error);
                    });
                }
            };
```

It gives me error = `$scope.post.put is not a function`

Comment: found any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

in your code, object $scope.post references following object

```
$scope.post = {};
```

And not your Rectangular rest service.